# selecting customers based on account status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a report of customers with the account status of COLLECTIONS and has more than 1 consecutive DECLINED charged.

```
Customer Table
=====================
CustomerID
FirstName
LastName
Email
Status (Collections)

Charge
=====================
ChargeID
CustomerID
DateCharged
Amount
ACK (Declined)

SELECT   Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, 
         Customer.Status, Charge.ChargeID, Charge.Amount, Charge.DateCharged, Charge.ACK
FROM     Customers
INNER JOIN Charge
ON Customer.CustomerID=Charge.CustomerID
AND Charge.ACK = 'Declined'
```

A customer has to have at least 2 DECLINED charges before they are sent to collections. How can I check to see if a customer has 2 declines?

Comment: You will need, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `COUNT`

Comment: Not putting this into an answer as it's only a direction, but how I normally handle this is add a row column which is partitioned by the customer  (using row number over and partition by keywords). You would then self join based on the row number and row number -1 for the customer. If the ACKs are both declined, you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would say just do an aggregation with a `having` clause.

However, your query suggests that you also want the details on the declines.  Instead, using a window function to calculate the total number of declines:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
             c.Status, ch.ChargeID, ch.Amount, ch.DateCharged, ch.ACK,
             sum(case when ch.ACK = 'Declined' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by c.customerId) as NumDeclines
      FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
           Charge ch
           ON c.CustomerID = ch.CustomerID
    ) cc
WHERE ACK = 'Declined' and NumDeclines >= 2
ORDER BY CustomerId, DateCharged;
```

If you just want the customers and not the detail, then do:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Status
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN
     Charge ch
     ON c.CustomerID = ch.CustomerID
WHERE ACK = 'Declined'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Statu
HAVING count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: I don't believe your solution finds CONSECUTIVE declined.

Comment: @SpectralGhost . . . The question is ambiguous.  It says "consecutive" in one place and it says "A customer has to have at least 2 DECLINED charges before they are sent to collections" in another.  The OP should really clarify the intent.

Comment: I took it to mean they needed 2 consecutive declines.

Comment: @GordonLinoff on the first query I got this error: Column 'Customers.CustomerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Use the alias c instead of he table name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff tried using the alias still got the GROUP BY error. The second query worked, but it gave me records with 2 or more. I just need a list of customers that have their last 2 declines.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the first query is what I'm looking for but I keep getting the GROUP BY error.

Comment: @Unohoo . . . Oops.  Somehow, I left out the `over` clause.  Clearly intended it (because I describe using a window function).  It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, this is how I would accomplish the task at hand.

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
    SELECT
             Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Charge.DateCharged DESC) AS [Row],
             Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, 
             Customer.Status, Charge.ChargeID, Charge.Amount, Charge.DateCharged, Charge.ACK
    FROM     Customers
    INNER JOIN Charge ON Customer.CustomerID=Charge.CustomerID
) a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
             Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Charge.DateCharged DESC) AS [Row],
             Customer.CustomerID, Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, 
             Customer.Status, Charge.ChargeID, Charge.Amount, Charge.DateCharged, Charge.ACK
    FROM     Customers
    INNER JOIN Charge ON Customer.CustomerID=Charge.CustomerID
) b ON a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID
WHERE a.[Row]=b.[Row]-1
AND a.ACK = 'Declined'
AND b.ACK = 'Declined'
AND a.[Row] IN (1,2)
AND b.[Row] IN (1,2)
```

Comment: it was a user error indeed (lol). sorry if I'm not making the issue clear. your query returns all accounts with 2 or more declines. i just need the last 2 declines on the account. so if a customer has 7 declines, I only need to return the last 2

Comment: @Unohoo Please clarify. My SQL should provide you with all accounts with 2 or more consecutive declines. Do their two most recent records need to be declined?

Comment: Try that. I switched from ASC to DESC ordering in the partion by and added row # checks to the where clause